# Design Automation API, Autodesk-Forge, c

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am new to design automation Api, looking for help to figure out that how I can upload a complete package into the cloud and get it back in a zip format. I have uploaded an Ipt file and got back modified file in bmp and Ipt. Now I am trying to do it again with assembly file (iam) or whole assembly in zip format, but it is giving me errors every time. I need to verify the format I am giving to cloud is correct.
[Format of Input passing in Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a75k1.png).

If it is not correct kindly briefly summarize the steps through which it can be completed.

One more thing, what I am looking for, according to descriptions given in format of Input and output that we can upload a zip file into the cloud. how can we upload zip file into a cloud and get back the modified results?

your remarks will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting. Without that I am really blind to what can be wrong.

Comment: @MichalVasicek Actually I am unable to understand the process for zip file. When I upload a zip file on cloud and process it. Cloud is unable to unzip that folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with zip files, you have to use pathInZip attribute of argument in workitem. For more info see https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-POST/ (BodyStructure -> Arguments -> XrefTree -> PathInZip)

In short, your input WorkItem argument referencing zip file needs to contain PathInZip attribute that references IAM or IPT file inside the zip structure you would like Inventor to open after downloading. If this argument's attribute is set processing will do unzipping for you to the folder named by the LocalName attribute.

Summary:

1. Set PathInZip so Inventor knows it needs to automatically unzip and what to open from zip.
2. Set LocalName so it knows where to unzip.